# There are 3 different colors and the colors repeat to the end of the table in order

Tags: php, css

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:200px; margin:auto">
    <?php
        $colors = array("#376ee5", "#3c763d", "#e2b70b");
        for($j = 1; $j < 11; $j++){ 
            for($i = 0; $i < count($colors); $i++){
                echo "<tr style='background-color:$colors[$i]'><td>$j</td><td>Student $j</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

How to create as shown in the picture?
Is there a way to create a column color like in the picture? Please help me

[image]

Comment: You could use CSS's `nth` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this by having an index for the `$colors` array that will cycle through 0-2:

```
$colors = array("#376ee5", "#3c763d", "#e2b70b");
$colorIndex = 0;
for($j = 1; $j < 11; $j++){
    echo "<tr style='background-color:$colors[$colorIndex]'><td>$j</td><td>Student $j</td></tr>";
    $colorIndex++;
    $colorIndex = $colorIndex > 2 ? 0 : $colorIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```css
td:nth-child(3n){
    background-color: #376ee5
}
td:nth-child(3n+1){
    background-color: #3c763d
}
td:nth-child(3n+2){
    background-color: #e2b70b
}
```